# Modifying rich comparison TypeError exception message for Generic Types

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have the following code where I create a generic type that supports comparison. When I compare different types, the code yields an exception (as expected). However, I want to modify the exception's message to make it more transparent.

Here is the code as it stands.

```py
import abc
import typing

class Comparable(typing.Protocol):
    """A simple protocol to signal to TypeVar that each 
        value will have a less than (lt) dunder available."""

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __lt__(self, other: typing.Any, /) -> bool:
        raise NotImplementedError

# each value that will be assigned to T will be 'Comparable', 
# i.e., meets Comparable's interface
T = typing.TypeVar("T", bound=Comparable)


class Node(typing.Generic[T]):
    """Acts as a wrapper around any value.
    This is to show in code the issue I am trying to fix"""

    def __init__(self, value: T) -> None:
        self.value = value

    def __lt__(self, __other: typing.Union[T, Node[T]]) -> bool:
        """Implements support for the '<' operator"""
        try:
            if isinstance(__other, Node):
                return self.value < __other.value
            return self.value < __other
        except TypeError:
            return NotImplemented
```

The code above works as expected, and MyPy is happy. Types are inferred when an instance of `Node` is created with some value, and `Node[type]` can be used to annotate, as expected.

Here is some example of using `Node` and the issue I am facing.

```py
value = Node(1)  # value: Node[int] = Node(1) -- value has a type of Node[int]
value2 = Node(2)  # likewise value2 has a type of Node[int]

# Example 1
print(
    value < 1
)  # -> False; the less than (lt) dunder can deal with Node[int] < int. 
# As you recall, __other is meant to accept T and Node[T]. 
# In this case, __other is 1, an int which is T.

# Example 2
print(
    value < value2
)  # -> True; the less than (lt) dunder should be able to deal with 
# Node[int] < Node[int] as __other would be Node[T]


# consider this
print(
    value < "0"
)  # As expected, this will fail because we cannot compare int and str; 
# likewise, we can't compare Node[int] with Node[str].
# Yields; <<Exeption>> 
# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Node' and 'str'
```

I am not sure if this is possible; however, I want to modify the output for the following exception such that it prints:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Node[int]' and 'str'
```

Because technically `<` **is** supported between `Node` and `str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you are out of luck, if you want to have that **exact same** error message but with the added type argument. The logic that handles the error message that you get, when a rich comparison method returns `NotImplemented` is an implementation detail of Python itself. You can for example see, how the error message is formed in the CPython 3.11.1 implementation of [`do_richcompare`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Objects/object.c#L700).

The closest you can get is modifying the error message and re-raising the `TypeError` manually, but it will include the entire stack trace including the line(s) from your `__lt__` method.

Here is a full working example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Any, Generic, Protocol, TypeVar, Union, cast


class Comparable(Protocol):
    def __lt__(self, other: Any, /) -> bool:
        ...


T = TypeVar("T", bound=Comparable)


class Node(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, value: T) -> None:
        self.value = value

    def __lt__(self, __other: Union[T, Node[T]]) -> bool:
        try:
            if isinstance(__other, Node):
                return self.value < __other.value
            return self.value < __other
        except TypeError as exc:
            # Modify exception message to to specify Node[T]
            # and raise the TypeError manually
            cls_name = self.value.__class__.__name__
            msg = cast(str, exc.args[0])
            msg = msg.replace(f"{cls_name}", f"Node[{cls_name}]", 1)
            if isinstance(__other, Node):
                cls_name = __other.value.__class__.__name__
                msg = msg.replace(
                    f"and '{cls_name}'",
                    f"and 'Node[{cls_name}]'",
                )
            exc.args = (msg, ) + exc.args[1:]
            raise exc


def test() -> None:
    print(Node(1) < 1)
    print(Node(1) < Node(2))
    # Node(1) < "0"
    # Node(1) < Node("0")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

The output like this is still `False` \ `True`.

If you uncomment `Node(1) < "0"`, you'll get something like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...].py", line 47, in <module>
    test()
  File "[...].py", line 42, in test
    Node(1) < "0"
  File "[...].py", line 36, in __lt__
    raise exc from None
  File "[...].py", line 22, in __lt__
    return self.value < __other
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Node[int]' and 'str'
```

If you instead uncomment the `Node(1) < Node("0")`, you'll get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...].py", line 47, in <module>
    test()
  File "[...].py", line 43, in test
    Node(1) < Node("0")
  File "[...].py", line 36, in __lt__
    raise exc from None
  File "[...].py", line 21, in __lt__
    return self.value < __other.value
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Node[int]' and 'Node[str]'
```

I suppose, if instead of modifying the message on the existing exeption instance, you raised an entirely new instance of `TypeError` and added `from None`, you could cut off one additional step in the stack trace message, but that could also cost you some potentially useful additional exception details in some situations.

---

On an unrelated note, there is no need for [`abc.abstractmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) on `Comparable.__lt__` because a `Protocol` may never be instantiated anyway. The method also doesn't need a body.

Comment: Thanks for your input once more, I really appreciate it. This certainly gives me a lot of think about. Moreover, thanks for the note on the Protocol class. 